# jruby-lint gem installed but no jrlint available?

Tags: jruby

I've recently started exploring JRuby using Joe Kutner's book *"Deploying with JRuby"*, but I've hit an issue when trying to install the **jruby-lint** gem.  Below is the output from my attempts, including the version numbers of Java, JRuby, and my OS.

I don't understand the output, especially why nokogiri wouldn't install as a jruby-lint dependency, but would install ok on its own.  While the jruby-lint gem is now reported as having installed correctly, it has not delivered a **jrlint** executable/script to use, and I don't know where to go from here.  Any ideas?

```
C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>jruby --version
jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) 2013-02-21 dac429b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_21-b11 [Windows 7-amd64]

C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>jruby -S gem install jruby-lint
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jruby-lint:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Dev/jruby-1.7.3/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.

   (root) at C:/Dev/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at C:/Dev/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
   (root) at extconf.rb:5


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Owen/.gem/jruby/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Owen/.gem/jruby/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
C:\Dev\jruby-1.7.3>jruby --version
jruby 1.7.3 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-02-21 dac429b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_21-b11 [Windows 7-amd64]

C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>jruby -S gem install jruby-lint
ERROR:  Error installing jruby-lint:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>jruby -S gem install nokogiri
Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.9-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.9-java
1 gem installed

C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>jruby -S gem install jruby-lint
Fetching: jruby-lint-0.4.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jruby-lint-0.4.1
1 gem installed

C:\Dev\repos\twitalytics>jrlint
'jrlint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar issue, also while working through this book.  Updating Rubygems solved it for me.  Perhaps try:

```
jruby -S gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that it tries to install the Ruby(not JRuby) version of Nokogiri cause it tries to install C extensions.

I think if you install the same version required by jruby-lint which is `nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1`, problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Neither solution here works for me on Windows. jruby -S gem install nokogiri
installs nokogiri-1.6.0-java
If I download the gem from https://github.com/jruby/jruby-lint and build it myself it leaves the gem folder empty at jruby\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\jruby-lint-0.4.1
And it won't make a bat file for running it in the /bin dir. I don't think this gem is ready for windows. Could it be that I'm trying to install it on BitNami stack? I haven't tried it with a regular install of JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

In case updating Rubygems doesn't work, try:

`gem install nokogiri`

This will install nokogiri-1.6.0-java

then again:

`gem install jruby-lint`

and you're good to go.